# Sorting neo4js lucene index queries in Cypher

Tags: lucene, neo4j, cypher

how can i write this example in a cypher query in web console?

```
hits = movies.query( "title", new QueryContext( "*" ).sort( "title" )
```

That's what i got so far. How can i add the sorting?

```
start a = node:movies("title:*") return a
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't depend on lucene's ordering. Cypher might not respect it if you do matching or aggregations.

Instead, I suggest you use Cypher's ordering:

start a = node:movies("title:*") return a order by a.title

Comment: In genereal, its still the same issue i posted yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125672/neo4j-cypher-query-performance-via-rest-on-centered-nodes I have 40k Nodes connected to a kind of "supernode". And i want to show only 10 of the nodes for pagination. My problem is, that ordering by title is really slow in that case. The idea was to let lucene do the sorting. The default cypher query takes 3,5 seconds to order all 40k nodes. Is there any other approach to those problems?

Comment: Yes, I think doing a Lucene sort might be a good idea. Look at http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/gremlin-plugin.html#rest-api-send-an-arbitrary-groovy-script---lucene-sorting for a groovy example...

Comment: Thanks Peter, i'll try and post the results here.